# sqlalchemy updates another model before deletion

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy with postgresql. And I'm newbie of sqlalchemy.

I made forien key for model "User" called "to_user_id" to model "Invitation" and this key is not nullable.

When I try to delete instance of model "User" using

```
session.delete(user)
```

And sqlalchemy set invitation's to_user_id to NULL automatically before deletion and postgresql raise following error.

```
IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) null value in column "to_user_id" violates not-null constraint
```

How can I disable it?

Here's my model's definition

```
class User(Base):
    '''
    User model
    '''
    __tablename__='User'
    id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True)

class Invitation(Base):
    '''
    Invitation model
    '''
    __tablename__ = 'Invitation'
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('appointment_id', 'to_user_id'),)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    appointment_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('Appointment.id',
        ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
    appointment = relationship('Appointment', backref=backref('invitations'),
    )

    from_user_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('User.id',
        ondelete='SET NULL'), nullable=True)
    from_user = relationship('User', backref=backref('sent_invitations'),
        primaryjoin='Invitation.from_user_id==User.id')

    to_user_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('User.id',
        ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
    to_user = relationship('User',backref=backref('received_invitations'),
        primaryjoin='Invitation.to_user_id==User.id',
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass `cascade='delete'` to the `to_user` `relationship()`. [See the docs here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_6/orm/relationships.html#the-relationship-api).

The `ondelete` argument to `ForeignKey` affects the generation of DDL statements, not how the ORM behaves.

Comment: I passed `cascade='delete'` to the `backref` and it works! Thank you :)

Comment: I see, the `backref` is indeed the right place rather than the `Invitation.to_user` relationship.